# Iterate through a dictionary with matrix

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, for-loop, matrix

I have this 2 matrix:

```
x = np.matrix("1 2 3; 4 5 6")
y = np.matrix("7 8 9; 10 11 12")
```

...and I put them in a dictionary

```
d = {"a" : x, "b": y}
```

Now I want to extract the values of the matrix that have the same position together, like this: 1,7...2,8...3,9... and so on until 6,12 (expected output).

I only managed to do it manually, like this:

```
   [value[0,0] for value in d.values()]
```

I´m trying to build a loop for this, but didn´t manage to do it.

Can someone give me a hand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
values = zip(*d.values()) # gives [([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12])]
pairs = []
for value in values:
    pairs.extend(zip(*value)) #adds (1, 7), (2, 8), ... to pairs list

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Output:

```
(1, 7)
(2, 8)
(3, 9)
(4, 10)
(5, 11)
(6, 12)
```

Comment: Note that the dictionary order is not guaranteed, so the output could end up being `(7, 1) (8, 2) (9, 3) (10, 4) (11, 5) (12, 6)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes, then we can simply use `values = zip(x, y)` instead of `values = zip(*d.values())`.

Comment: Not that this is any better, but `pairs = zip(*[v.flat for v in d.values()])`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get the same result. Maybe it's because I'm using python 3(?). I tried to write the first line this way:
`values = list(zip(*d.values()))`
but I get this result: 
`[(matrix([[1, 2, 3]]), matrix([[7, 8, 9]])),
 (matrix([[4, 5, 6]]), matrix([[10, 11, 12]]))]`
which is also the result I get if I run the whole code.
Meanwhile I came up with an alternative solution: 
`for x in range(0,2):
    for y in range(0,3):
        print([value[x, y] for value in d.values()])`
but it would still interest me how to use the zip() function.

Comment: @anplaceb Oh that's because you're using numpy arrays and I used Python lists. My code *is* Python3, so no compatibility issues. And I like your solution. By the way, you can convert to a usual list by doing something like `x_list = numpy.array(x).reshape(-1,).tolist()`. Then, you can proceed with the code above.